# Oracle SQL missing comma error code ORA-00917

Tags: sql, oracle, variable-assignment, ora-00917

Oracle SQL says this error ORA-00917: missing comma.  Can you explain what's wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT (
    ASSIGN_NUM      CHAR(3),
    ASSIGN_DATE     DATE,
    PROJ_NUM        CHAR(3),
    EMP_NUM             CHAR(3),
    ASSIGN_JOB              CHAR(4),
    ASSIGN_CHR_HR       NUMBER(8,2),
    ASSIGN_HOUR         NUMBER(8,2),
    ASSIGN_CHARGE        NUMBER(8,2));

DESCRIBE ASSIGNMENT


INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('1001','20-MAR-2006','18','103','503','84.50','3.5','295.75';
```

Comment: Besides the missing ")" at the end of the insert its arguably bad practice to exclude column names from the insert statement. Why? As soon as someone adds another column to the table, the insert will break. In addition, referencing the table's name in column names, such as ASSIGN_NUM, ASSIGN_JOB, ASSIGN_CHARGE etc. is considered a code "smell". Instead consider using NUM, JOB, CHARGE, etc..

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('1001','20-MAR-2006','18','103','503','84.50','3.5','295.75');
```

Comment: sory i cant get your answer. can u write it .

Answer (score 4):

You missed `right parenthisis` at end of query.

```
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES (
  '1001','20-MAR-2006','18','103','503','84.50','3.5','295.75';
                                                           ^^^^^ 
                                                       Here you missing )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this insert:

```
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('1001',TO_DATE('20-MAR-2006','DD-MON-YYYY'),'18','103','503','84.50','3.5','295.75');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this as you can't insert quotes in numbers:

`INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('1001',TO_DATE('20-MAR-2006','DD-MON-YYYY'),'18','103','503',84.50,3.5,295.75);`